# Resetting rating provided while using asp.net ajax rating control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have used ASP.NET Ajax Rating control in my webpage and so far everything is fine.I have one issue with it though.Currently the user is able to click on any star(1-5) to specify their rating.However once clicked the user is not able to reset the the rating i.e after clicking a particular star he/she might choose to not rate at all and leave all the stars empty.With JavaScript I have been able to do that i.e empty out all the stars however if the user hovers again on the stars ,the star that he had chosen earlier persists and remains highlighted.

Is there anyway we could reset the rating provided ?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a built-in feature; you would have to programmably store the value in a variable, tap into the appropriate events to make that happen.  So the answer is yes, but manually.  There is no built-in event, but should be achievable by listening to the mouseover event of the underlying HTML element...  Or instead put a clear button next to the rating to reset it.